# How to display a report in IFrame in CRM, when CRM is in offline mode (all network connections are disabled)?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have created a SSRS report and uploaded it to report server. On my Opportunity product form I am using a IFrame to display this report.

I am passing parameters to this report by checking " Pass record object-type code and unique identifier as parameters " checkbox on iframe.

Iframe is displaying report as i wish in online mode only. When I changed the crm to offline mode and disabled all the network connections, IFrame is not displaying report, it's giving me error message "Internet explorer cannot display the web page". How can I display the report in CRM offline mode with all network connections disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you're not going to reach the report server if you can't access it.  I would check in your form load script whether you are online or offline and then give an appropriate message that the report can't be displayed.